# Android: How to set bold / bigger outline on a Edittext

Tags: android

I have a EditText on my View and i would like to set his outline on bold or bigger than she is.
Is it possible with xml?

Thank you.

Comment: So, the larger the edit text is (to a threshold), apply bold effect?

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand you...

Comment: I'm asking if you can rephrase your question, cause I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, so: i have a EditText on my layout. An edittext has a cotnour (outline
) which is grey and pretty thin, I would like to increase his thickness or make it bold.

Comment: I think you will need to create your own image to accomplish that.

Comment: Ok thank you; If you agree, you can answer this question and I will set this as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can just modify the thinkness of the borderlines of an EditText. However, you could accomplish something similar with [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html).